# biggest significance vs. most significance?

Tags: grammar

Which of these is correct in this context:

> What do you see as having the (biggest significance OR most significance) in the field of economics?

Comment: Hi Kathy, and welcome to ELL! There's plenty of people here ready and willing to help people who are learning English, but we really do focus on that - helping people learn, rather than proofreading or correcting. That means it's much better if you include some idea of what you've done to try to figure it out for yourself, and what you think of the different options.

Answer (score 1):

**Biggest significance** = I have many options. all of them are important and can't be done without, but there's one option among all the options I have that rules above all. One option that is nearly impossible to do without.

**Most significance** = I have many options, but one option is extremely important compared to the other ones. The other options pale in comparison to this option, it is the option that stands out the most and that must be given more attention to.

Which one is correct? it really depends on your context. So far we don't have enough context to point out which one of those two words is more fitting for that context.